# Inline Javascript stoped adding class to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Hey I have an inline javascript code that adds a class to an element and makes it slide up in the screen. But it suddenly stopped working and I don't know why. Here's the HTMl and JS:

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 400) {
            $(".converter").addClass("atcbottomactive");
        } else {
            $(".converter").removeClass("atcbottomactive");
        }
    });
```

```css
.converter {
 position: fixed; 
 height: 60px; 
 width: 100%; 
 bottom: -200; 
 background: #eeeeee; 
 transition: 1s;
 z-index: 10000;
}

.ccontent {
 display: inline-flex;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px 5%;
}

.atcbottomactive{
 bottom:0;
 transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background: green; height: 1500px; width: 100%;"></div>
<div class="converter"><div class="ccontent">...</div></div>
```

Here's the [link](https://azaz.com.br)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @vsync "So many ways" - seems a bit of an overstatement. Hypothetically you never, ever *"need"* jQuery, nor do we know if this tiny snippet is the specific reason that OP is using it. That leaves one issue (the repeated DOM lookups), and while I agree (and would suggest OP implement stored lookups), this specific snippet wouldn't really produce noticeable slowdowns.

Comment: @vsync, ok. What would be your suggestion? Just starting in JS (:

Comment: @Fernando You should consider applying some CSS along the lines of  `body { height: 200vh; }` in your question, to ensure a scrollbar appears. Without scrollable content, we can't replicate the scroll behavior.

Comment: @TylerRoper, thanks! Just added CSS :) Basically the div.content is located -200 px and I use JS to add a class and make it comes up. But the JS is the problem, its not adding the class to makes it comes up when I scroll the page over 400px.

Comment: @Fernando The CSS that you've included doesn't produce scrollbars.

Comment: @TylerRoper, sorry, done! if you need more info you can check the link I provided because here the code worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193794/discussion-between-fernando-and-tyler-roper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, trying to use it without including JQuery gives you the error. You can solve this easily with "JavaScript" without using jQuery.

```js
var element = document.querySelector(".converter");

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

  var scroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  if (scroll >= 400) {
    element.classList.add("atcbottomactive");
  } else {
    element.classList.remove("atcbottomactive");
  }

});
```

```css
.converter {
  padding: 20px 20px 200%;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.converter.atcbottomactive {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="converter">
  <div class="ccontent">Scroll me: 400px</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `var element = document.querySelector(".converter")` should be declared **outside** of the scroll callback function.